# While loop is taking forever and freezing screen?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this large program, one of whose parts includes the click of a button (this GUI was made in wxPython). Basically, the button is a timer, and when you click on it, the text of the button switches based on the time left, e.g. 5 Seconds, 4 Seconds, 3 Seconds... For some reason, though, when I click on the button in the GUI, the entire program freezes and I have to force quit the app. (Everything else in the app works fine and responds, until I click on this one button). Here is the event handler that is called when the button is clicked.

Thanks in advance!

```
    def TossUpTimer(self, event):
        while self.tossuptimer > -1:
            while self.tossuptimer > 0:
                self.tossupbutton.SetLabel(str(self.tossuptimer) + "Seconds")
                time.sleep(1)
                self.tossuptimer -= 1
            if self.tossuptimer == 0:
                self.tossupbutton.SetLabel("Time is Up!")
                time.sleep(1)
                self.tossupbutton.SetLabel(str(self.tossuptimer) + "Seconds")
        self.tossuptimer = 5
```

Comment: Looks like it only decrements to 0, so it's always greater than -1, but at that point it never gets altered any more because it's not greater than 0... ergo, infinite loop

Comment: Suggest you to use 'break' to terminate the program & also what @JonClements suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Why your GUI app freezes](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/10/why-your-gui-app-freezes.html) is an attempt to explain the basic idea, and all of the different options for dealing with it.

But here's a short version:

The whole point of a GUI app is that it's running an *event loop*, responding to events as they come in from the user or the OS. You write *handlers* for particular events. Until your handler returns, the GUI can't process the next event. That means that the entire app is frozen.

You need to return from your handler as quickly as possible. What you can't do, ever, is `time.sleep(1)` or a long `while` loop or anything of the kind directly in a handler.

There are various ways around this. The two most common are to ask the event loop to run some of your code later, or to move it to a background thread. (`wx` adds a third way, `SafeYield` and friends, which is appropriate in some cases, but probably not what you want here.)

---

For the first alternative, the idea is that, instead of looping around `sleep`, you write a function that handles a single iteration of the loop, and schedule a *timer* to fire that function once/second. This is known as "turning your control flow inside out", which can be a bit hard to get your head around.

Unfortunately, I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, because, as Jon Clements points out, your logic doesn't make sense even in a sequential program. But I'll write something simple: when you click the button, it will count down once/second for 5 seconds, then stop counting.

```
def OnTossUpTimer(self, event):
    self.tossuptimer -= 1
    if self.tossuptimer > 0:
        self.tossupbutton.SetLabel(str(self.tossuptimer) + "Seconds")
    else:
        self.tossupbutton.SetLabel("Time is Up!")
        self.tossuptimer_timer.Stop()

def TossUpTimer(self, event):
    self.tossuptimer = 5
    self.tossupbutton.SetLabel(str(self.tossuptimer) + "Seconds")
    self.tossuptimer_timer = wx.Timer(self)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTossUpTimer, self.tossuptimer_timer)
    self.tossuptimer_timer.Start(1000, False)
```

See [Using wx.Timers](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/25/wxpython-using-wx-timers/) and the [`Timer`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Timer-class.html) docs for more details.

---

The threaded version is simpler in some ways, more complicated in others. You can leave your sequential logic alone, but you can't talk to any GUI widgets except indirectly, by calling `PostEvent`. So:

```
class LabelUpdateEvent(wx.PyEvent):
    EVT_LABEL_UPDATE_ID = wx.NewId()
    def __init__(self, data):
        wx.PyEvent.__init__(self)
        self.SetEventType(EVT_LABEL_UPDATE_ID)
        self.data = data

def SetLabelOnMainThread(self, value):
    wx.PostEvent(self.SetLabelForReal, ResultEvent(value))

def SetLabelForReal(self, event):
    self.tossupbutton.SetLabel(event.data)

def TossUpTimerThread(self):
    self.tossuptimer = 5
    while self.tossuptimer > 0:
        self.SetLabelOnMainThread(str(self.tossuptimer) + "Seconds")
            time.sleep(1)
            self.tossuptimer -= 1
    self.SetLabelOnMainThread(str(self.tossuptimer) + "Time is Up!")

def TossUpTimer(self, event):
    threading.Thread(target=self.TossUpTimerThread).start()
```

If you're doing a lot of this, you probably want to write more generic "on-main-thread" functions, instead of all this boilerplate for each function. (You can, in fact, write a single completely-generic function, which `wxPython` really ought to come with but doesn't.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new to wxPython. Could you show me how I could edit my code above to have it execute the same purpose? The button object is `self.tossupbutton`.

Comment: @user3059347: What exactly do you want me to show you? I've given you two different sample implementations, and explained what they do, and explained that I didn't try to implement exactly the same thing as your original code because your original code is just an infinite loop. If this isn't enough to get you started, I suspect you need to read some basic tutorials.

Comment: Never mind. I get it after reading your link to using wxTimers. Thanks!

Comment: I used your first solution that uses wx Timers. Thanks again!

Comment: Above the call of duty and a braver man than I... I deliberately didn't want to address the whole GUI eventloop and was hoping the OP would fix the immediate problem and discover this later on... But... fantastic answer... Would like to more than +1, but oh well :)